# Cloud Firestore QuerySnapshot Where function field not supported

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Cloud Firebase on my android app and I want to filter my documents using where function to avoid unnecessary billing cost, my problem is instead of using document field inside my where function I prefer model to filter my data due to multiple advantage, then I try below code, but it trough error of

> "'field is String || field is FieldPath || field == FieldPath.documentId': Supported [field] types are [String] and [FieldPath].,"

**I try this**

```js
final authPhoneNo = Utils.formatPhoneNo(phoneNo!);
CollectionReference receiptCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('example');
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot;

querySnapshot = await receiptCollection.orderBy('Date', descending: true).where((e){
    Utils.formatPhoneNo(MainData.fromJson(e.data()).userPhoneNo!);
}, isEqualTo: authPhoneNo).get();
```

**`formatPhoneNo`**

```js
static formatPhoneNo(String phoneNo) => phoneNo.replaceAll(RegExp(r"\D"), "")
    .substring(
        (phoneNo.replaceAll(RegExp(r"\D"), "").length) - 9,
        (phoneNo.replaceAll(RegExp(r"\D"), "").length)
    );
```

It through error on where((e)

> 'field is String || field is FieldPath || field == FieldPath.documentId': Supported [field] types are [String] and [FieldPath].

Comment: What does your formatPhoneNo() function do? Would you mind attaching it?

Comment: @imperial-lord hey I attached formatPhoneNo function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you provided, I see that you want to filter data using `where` and a formatter function `formatPhoneNo`, but this is not how it works according to the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#dart_1):

> ```js
> // Create a reference to the cities collection  
> final citiesRef = db.collection("cities");
> // Create a query against the collection.  
> final query = citiesRef.where("state", isEqualTo:  "CA");
> ```

As you can see, the first parameter on the `where` clause refers to the field you want to filter and the second one refers to the [query operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators) you want to perform (in this case,  `isEqualTo`) and the reference value (in the example, the string `"CA"`).

In your case, the right way to do the query would be as follows:

```js
querySnapshot = await receiptCollection.where('phoneNo', isEqualTo: authPhoneNo).get();
```

To avoid the use of a formatter, which leads to unnecessary processing time every time it is called and; in this case could lead to format every result until the desired value matches the condition if its done without the where Firebase function, I would recommend to sanitize your data before saving it to Firebase as recommended in this [article](https://www.hlrlookup.com/10-practices-to-clean-your-phone-number-database/):

> ### 2. Standardize phone number formatting
>
> When you capture telephone data, either directly from the customer or via an ingress from a data supplier, you should standardize the telephone number format. Ideally, you should use the industry-standard  [E.164 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164)
> ...
> If you prefer to display a telephone number in a nice to read human format you can still store the number in your database in E.164 format but present the number on the screen in a friendly format.

Doing this way, you could filter your data saved in Firebase using simple and compound queries as shown in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).